# Timeline graph in Visual Studio 2012 profiler missing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, profiler

For some unknown reason the timeline graph shown on the summary page in Visual Studio 2012 is missing. This is the first time I use the profiler on a new computer and it just isn't there.

This is of course a huge issue as I am not able to filter which part of the run to profile. Typically I want to exclude initialization parts etc.

I've searched high and low for an option to enable/disable it but there seems to be none.

I tried to reinstall VS2012, but that did not help.

Has anyone experienced the same issue and does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Hi there this is Andre from VS profiler team. What kind of application were you trying to profile?

Comment: Hi there, just reaching out again, were you ever able to get this resolved?